# Bash - создание символических ссылок со случайными названиями

Tags: bash, unix, shell

Имеется такая команда:

```
find / -iname "*.mp3" -exec ln -sv {} $(pwd)/folder/ \;
```

Данная команда ищет все файлы с расширением .mp3, и создает на них символьные ссылки в каталоге folder.
Вопрос: как, используя $RANDOM, правильно записать команду, чтобы имена созданных ссылок были случайными?

Comment: может лучше `mktemp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
find / -iname *.mp3 | while read fmp
do
        echo "${fmp}"  # для отладки   
        ln -sv "${fmp}"  `pwd`/folder/$RANDOM
done;
```